# I want to service_code parameter value for Australia Post Shipping method..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm Integrating Australia Post Shipping rate calculation.

Here is My Code :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult Calculation()
        {
            var lngth = "10";
            var wdth = "10";
            var hgth = "10";
            var fpcode = "3216";
            var tpcode = "3217";
            var weght = "5";
            var service_code = "AUS_PARCEL_Courier";

            string url = "https://auspost.com.au/api/postage/parcel/domestic/calculate.json?";
            url = url + "length=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(lngth) + "&width=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(wdth) + "&height=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(hgth) + "&from_postcode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fpcode) + "&to_postcode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tpcode) + "&option_code=&weight=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(weght) + "&service_code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(service_code) + "&extra_cover=";
            Uri objURI = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest objwebreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(objURI);
            objwebreq.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8;";

            objwebreq.Method = "Get";
            objwebreq.Timeout = 15000;

            objwebreq.Headers.Set("AUTH-KEY", "enter your auth key");

            HttpWebResponse objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objwebreq.GetResponse();
            Stream objStream = objWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
            var a = objStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return null;
        }
```

this is my working code, But I want to service_code parameter value For below shipping method:

1) Australia Post. Courier

2) Australia Post. Express

3) Australia Post. Standard

4) Australia Post. Economy Air

Thanks, Kaushik.

Comment: dont forget to invalidate and change your auth key, now that youve posted it on a public forum

Comment: @Tewr auth key is using for testing purpose acccount so dont worry about that.

Comment: Are you saying "AUS_PARCEL_Courier" doesn't work? Anyway, presumably they publish a spec somewhere for their API.

Comment: @DylanNicholson yes, AUS_PARCEL_Courier doesn't work.

Comment: might be case-sensitive. try all upper ([this](https://github.com/fontis/auspost-api-php/blob/master/src/Auspost/Postage/Enum/ServiceCode.php) piece of library, working or not, uses all upper chars)

Comment: @Tewr i try both but doesn't work.

Comment: https://developers.auspost.com.au/apis/pac/reference/postage-letter-domestic-service

Comment: @DylanNicholson there is only REGULAR and EXPRESS method, not other shipping method

Comment: Not sure why I'm doing your googling for you but try here https://github.com/fontis/auspost-api-php/blob/master/src/Auspost/Postage/Enum/ServiceCode.php

Answer (score 0):

```
AUS_LETTER_EXPRESS_SMALL => Express Post Small Envelope
AUS_LETTER_REGULAR_LARGE => Large Letter
AUS_PARCEL_COURIER => Courier Post
AUS_PARCEL_COURIER_SATCHEL_MEDIUM => Courier Post Assessed Medium Satchel
AUS_PARCEL_EXPRESS => Express Post
AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR => Parcel Post

INT_PARCEL_COR_OWN_PACKAGING => International Courier
INT_PARCEL_EXP_OWN_PACKAGING => International Express
INT_PARCEL_STD_OWN_PACKAGING => International Standard
INT_PARCEL_AIR_OWN_PACKAGING => International Economy Air
INT_PARCEL_SEA_OWN_PACKAGING => International Economy Sea

For Extra Cover
AUS_SERVICE_OPTION_SIGNATURE_ON_DELIVERY => Signature on Delivery
AUS_SERVICE_OPTION_COURIER_EXTRA_COVER_SERVICE => Standard cover

Below is a postman example for "Parcel Post = AUS_PARCEL_REGULAR"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykg7R.jpg